# Ubuntu Change default user when username has spaces

Tags: cmd, ubuntu-18.04

How would I write my command to make the command prompt reckognize the space in my username?

I'm trying to change the default user on my ubuntu system, but since my username has space in it, it creates some trouble.

I have both tried to use the back slash

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ubuntu1804 config --default-user Oskar\ B
```

And also use quotation marks

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ubuntu1804 config --default-user 'Oskar B'
```

Both of these return **Error: 0x80070057 Incorrect parameter.**

How do I avoid this?

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` supports only one possibility to interpret a space character as literal character of an argument string and not as separator between the argument strings: the argument string is enclosed in `"`. That is explained by the help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window. So the solution is most likely the usage of `ubuntu1804 config --default-user "Oskar B"`.

Comment: @Mofi
That returns the same error, but it also says "/usr/bin/id: extra operand ‘B’
Try '/usr/bin/id --help' for more information."

Comment: Have you tried `"'Oskar B'"`?

Comment: Ok, using backslash while putting the name in quotation works!

Comment: @OskarB, what is your working result? Where is the REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) used? (See, even SO makes the username with no SPACE characters.)

Comment: @lit The working result is adding reverse backslash inside double quotation marks, so C:\WINDOWS\system32>ubuntu1804 config --default-user "Oskar\ B"